# querySelector returns undefined string when trying to access numeric value as the ID of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectors-api

`querySelector()` returns `undefined string` when trying to access `numeric value as the ID` of an element. I would like to use `querySelector()` method over others, because it is more flexible. 
Any solutions to this problem would be a great help.

```
var foo = document.querySelector('#1');
console.log(foo);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnd7K/1/)**

Comment: Chrome complains _Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified._

Comment: Please note, that naming id that it would start from numbers is against specs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weird .. Anyway this: `document.querySelector('[id="1"]')` is working. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wnd7K/2/

Comment: If we refer to this HTML4 spec, the id should not be started with number bytheway

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the ids of the elements so that they begin with a letter solves your problem e.g. : 
`<div id="a1"></div>`